# Is there any non-global seeded random in LUA?

Tags: random, lua

Is there any **non-global** method of generating a seeded random number in LUA?

The function `math.randomseed()` sets the seed for the whole application (which is less than ideal) and if the code is executed async there is a risk that other parts of the application "steals" numbers from the sequence.

One good example from C# is the Random class where you can initialize a Random instance with a seeded number rather than setting the seed for the whole application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Pure Lua PCG-like [PRNG](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/375ffe05075063c9a2ce61bb30b1ce50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [lrandom](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#lrandom) library provides independent streams of random numbers. It can also reset and clone streams.

lrandom is a C library. For a plain Lua solution, see [mt19937ar-lua](https://github.com/davebollinger/mt19937ar-lua).

Answer (score 4):

## No.

You might find some third-party library that does this though.